# Can we get a better error message if our browser is too old?

Tags: feature-request, login

For about 6 weeks I had to reset my mobile and forgot afterwards to update the browser apps (yes, my fault), so I was not able to make a full login on Stack Exchange. It would be nice to get a more applicable error message, if it is possible. It took me 4 weeks to find out what was wrong.

Comment: Do you have an image of that error message, or can you quote it?

Comment: I was suspicious that was the only thing @Joachim